# How to force pkgrepo refresh only one time per highstate?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a bunch of packages in a private debian repository. Following salt documentation (http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkgrepo.html), in a salt state I defined a pkgerepo entry like this:

```
my-private-repo:
   pkgrepo.managed:
     - hmanname: My Deb
     - name: deb <url>....
     - dist: my-repo
     - require_in:
       - pkg: pkg1
       - pkg: pkg2
       - pkg: ...
```

and in each pkg definition added the refresh: True stanza:

```
pkg1:
  pkg:
    - latest
    - fromrepo: my-repo
    - refresh: True
```

Now, it works in the sense that I get an "apt-get update" before installing (upgrading) each package, but there are quite a few of them (around 20) and I get an update for each one. Is there a way to have apt update just once after the repo state has been tested?

Answer (score 2):

Helices and Antstud answers put me in the right direction. Anyway in the end I found out some interesting things that might be helpful for others:

1. "refresh: True" is useless with pkg.latest, seems like 'latest' implies  "refresh: True"
2. What's stated in SaltStack doc seems not to apply (at last with version 2014.7.1)

   > require_in:
   >
   > Set this to a list of pkg.installed or pkg.latest to trigger the running of apt-get update prior to attempting to install these packages. Setting a require in the pkg will not work for this.

   I just added

`- require:
  - pkgrepo: my_repo`

to my pkg definition and it's working (making includes less of a mess).

Comment: The problem related with the useless "refresh" was fixed in commit aa29744c285451e9ea066fd076ab4a39cb2490e1 (2016-02-18), and is applied in the release 2016.3.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just install multiple packages with a single state by using `pkgs:`. It works for me, even with a custom repository:

```
install packages:
  pkg:
    - latest
    - fromrepo: my-repo
    - refresh: True
    - pkgs:
      - pkg1
      - pkg2
      ...
```

Comment: Well this workaround is ok, it lighten the problem, but does not solve it: many packages are installed together on every minion, others are on some minion and some not, this is why each pkg has it's own sls. Anyway I can try to group them differently and use your solution anyway for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define pkg list in the pillars for every minion and than get the list in the state.

```
install packages:
  pkg:
    - latest
    - fromrepo: my-repo
    - refresh: True
    - pkgs:
      {% for pkg in pillar.get('packages', {}).items() %}
      {{pkg}}
      {% endfor %}
```